# Highcharts - curves goes outside the box

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image: Curves outside box - highcharts]

Curve goes sometimes outside the box. I tried to play with margins and height to give it more space but couldn't get my way arround it..

Any ideas fellas ?

Comment: can you post jsFiddle example?

Comment: Hi Igor, It would be complicated a bit, I'm using my own php layer to generate the highcharts... I'm just wondering how would I give it more space above so the whole line would appear

Comment: Copy the generated code HTML/JS to jsfiddle, not your PHP

Comment: Check your `min` and `max` limits for yAxis and increase at least `max`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting different values for yAxis `max` parameter. For example, set it to 2 or some greater value:

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'messages'
    },
    labels: {
        y: 20
    },
    min: 0,
    max: 2,
    ...
```